# Creating this pattern in Java? (My loop isn't working)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to create a program that depends on user input for integers between 2 and 10.

If the user entered four, this should be the output:

```
     ****                 
    *    *      
   *      *       
  *        *     
 *          *        
*            *              
*            *              
*            *              
*            *              
 *          *                               
  *        *
   *      *
    *    *
     ****
```

I want an input of 4 to output four stars in the first line to make a horizontal edge, and then a 4-star diagonal. Then four stars along a vertical “edge”, before repeating the diagonal and horizontal edge.

So I can draw the first line, last and middle lines right but my diagonals won't even show the spaces for some reason!

```
     ****
**
**
**
**
*            *
*            *
*            *
*            *
**
**
**
**
     ****
```

This is my code (I'm a beginner but I've been trying to fix this a lot and I really need some help):

```
    int num = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a value between 2 and 10.");
    num = keyNum.nextInt();
    while (num < 2 || num > 10) {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid number please.");
        num = keyNum.nextInt();
    } 
    for (int a = 0; a < num + 1; a++) 
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < num; b++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < num; c++)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int d = num; d < 1; d--) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
        for (int e = (num * 3) - 2; e < num; e++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (int f = 0; f < num; f++)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("*");
        for (int g = 0; g < num * 3; g++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < num; h++)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = num; i < 1; i--) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
        for (int j = (num * 3) - 2; j < num; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    for (int k = 0; k < num + 1; k++) 
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < num; l++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: `for (int d = num; d < 1; d--)`??? Did you mean `for (int d = num; d > c; d--)`?

Comment: lots of compilation errors. remove them and post a clean code

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar Other than missing declaration of the `Scanner keyNum` variable, there are no compilation errors in that code.

Comment: I'm only having trouble with the sections that are supposed to print out a diagonal line. The spaces before the stars and the middle spaces are not showing up and they aren't increasing/decreasing for some reason.

Comment: @Andreas Yep. Misread it (skipped over the 'ln'). Whoops.

Comment: The printing of diagonal lines doesn't work because your looping logic is way off. First ask yourself how those spacing loops could work without using the iteration variable of the outer loop, e.g. the `d` and `e` loops don't use the value of `c`, so how can that ever work? Look at the code again and re-think what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work
Just changed couple of `for` loop conditions

```
        while (num < 2 || num > 10) {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number please.");
            num = keyNum.nextInt();
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < num + 1; a++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < num; b++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < num; c++)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int d = num; d > c; d--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            for (int e = num * 2; e < (num * 3) + (c *2);  e++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int f = 0; f < num; f++)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("*");
            for (int g = 0; g < num * 3; g++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        for (int h = 1; h <= num; h++)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            for (int j = 0; j < (num * 3) - (h * 2) ; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < num + 1; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < num; l++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
```